Caliburn.Micro how to write a extract a action to resource so that other similar element can reuse it?
I am writing a simple calculator program in WPF,and used Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework.I defined the UI in XMAL like this
<Button Name="Clear" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource grey_button}" Content="C"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource grey_button}" Content="+/-"/>
<Button Name="Remainder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource grey_button}" Content="%"/>
<Button Name="Division" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="÷"/>

<Button Name="Seven" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="7"/>
<Button Name="Eight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="8"/>
<Button Name="Nine" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="9"/>
<Button Name="Multiply" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="x"/>

<Button Name="Four" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="4"/>
<Button Name="Five" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="5"/>
<Button Name="Six" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="6"/>
<Button Name="Plus" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="+"/>

<Button Name="One" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="1">
</Button>
<Button Name="Two" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="2"/>
<Button Name="Three" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="3"/>
<Button Name="Subtract" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="-" FontSize="25"/>

<Button Name="Dot" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="·"/>
<Button Name="Zero" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="0"/>
<Button Name="Backward" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="x"/>
<Button Name="Equal" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="="/>


In this way,i actually can handle the click action because of Caliburn naming Conversion as i define One,Two,Three .... method in my ViewModel
public void Zero()
{
    Input += "0";
}

public void One(string content)
{
    Input += "1";

}

public void Two()
{
    Input += "2";
}

public void Three()
{
    Input += "3";
}

public void Four()
{
    Input += "4";
}

Now i want to handle all input action with one method
public void Input(string content)
{
   Input+=content;
}


So i imported Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors  as namespace b in the top of view,and defined the following event in one of my button

<Button Name="One" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource white_button}" Content="1">
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="One">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=One, Path=Content}"></cal:Parameter>
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>



Problmen:
I want to reuse the code about Triggers,and I know i should extract this trigger logic to resouce,and i can used it like this:
 <Button Name="One" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="1" Action={StaticResource InputAction,Parameter=Binding{ElementName=One Path=Content}}/>

 <Button Name="Two" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="2" Action={StaticResource InputAction,Parameter=Binding{ElementName=Two Path=Content}}/>

 <Button Name="Three" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="3" Action={StaticResource InputAction,Parameter=Binding{ElementName=Three Path=Content}}/>

...

 <Button Name="Plus" Style="{StaticResource blue_button}" Content="+" Action={StaticResource InputAction,Parameter=Binding{ElementName=Plus Path=Content}}/>



The main way to set the action of the button is to use commands. In a typical Solution with GUI on WPF, it is common to implement the MVVM pattern. In this case, commands are set in the ViewModel. You can pass a parameter to the commands for its further processing. In a very simplified form, I will show you the implementation in which the ViewModel also performs the functions of the Model.
The example uses my implementation of ViewModelBase . You can replace it with any convenient for you. Or, if you are interested in my implementation, you can take it from this repository: https://github.com/INexteR/NewTrade/tree/main/NewTradeSln/ViewModels
using Simplified;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core2024.SO.huojian.question78746674
{
    public class CalculatorViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> ButtonNames { get; }
            = Array.AsReadOnly("C, +/-, %, ÷, ✖, +, -, ., =, , 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...Any Names"
                                .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries));

        public CalculatorViewModel()
        {
            DisplayedValue = "0";
        }

        public RelayCommand CalculatorCommand => GetCommand<string>(CalculatorExecute, CalculatorCanExecute);

        private bool CalculatorCanExecute(string parameter)
            => ButtonNames.Contains(parameter);

        public string DisplayedValue { get => Get<string>(); private set => Set(value); }

        private void CalculatorExecute(string parameter)
        {
            string value = DisplayedValue;
            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "0":
                case "1":
                case "2":
                case "3":
                case "4":
                case "5":
                case "6":
                case "7":
                case "8":
                case "9":
                    if (value == "0")
                        value = string.Empty;
                    value = value + parameter;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    value = "0";
                    break;
                case "+/-":
                    if (value != "0")
                    {
                        if (value[0] == '-')
                            value = value.Substring(1);
                        else
                            value = "-" + value;
                    }
                    break;

                // Logic of other buttons

                default:
                    break;
            }
            DisplayedValue = value;
        }

    }
}

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.huojian.question78746674.CalculatorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.huojian.question78746674"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CalculatorWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CalculatorViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <Style x:Key="base" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="button.command" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource base}">
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding CalculatorCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 5"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="button.white_button" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource button.command}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="button.blue_button" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource button.command}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayedValue, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource base}" IsReadOnly="True"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                 Padding="15 5"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="4">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="C"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="+/-"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="%"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="÷"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="7"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="8"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="9"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="✖"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="4"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="5"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="6"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="+"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="1"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="2"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="3"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="-" FontSize="25"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="·"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.white_button}" Content="0"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content=""/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource button.blue_button}" Content="="/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>


